# SQL Join, not sure of exact syntax in complex query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to match up two bits of data, adding to an existing query.

I'm hoping the query itself explains what i'm trying to do. The line I'm having trouble with is LEFT JOIN practitioners p ON insolvencies.practitioner = practitioners.id,

```
SELECT DISTINCT     i.id            AS  id,
                    i.company       AS  company,
                    i.insolvencyDate AS insolvency_date,
                    i.city          AS  city,
                    i.createdOn     AS  createdOn,
                    1               AS  rank_id,
                    t.entryCopy     AS  insolvency_type,
                    i.businessNature AS business_nature,
                    p.name          AS pract_comp_name,
                    'I'             AS  i_type 
    FROM     insolvencies i, 
        LEFT JOIN practitioners p ON insolvencies.practitioner = practitioners.id, 
        lookupcopy t 
    WHERE    i.checked   =  1    
        AND t.id     =  i.insolvencyType 
        AND i.insolvencyDate    >=  {ts '2010-01-22 00:00:00'} 
        AND i.insolvencyDate    <=  {ts '2011-10-20 00:00:00'} 
        AND (LOWER(p.name)   LIKE   '%Hodgsons%') 
    GROUP BY     id
```

Comment: Perfect example of why mixing ANSI-86 and ANSI-92 style joins is probably not a good idea

Comment: Really helpful to me at my skill level, that Conrad. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT i.id AS id
     , i.company AS company
     , i.insolvencyDate AS insolvency_date
     , i.city AS city
     , i.createdOn AS createdOn
     , 1 AS rank_id
     , t.entryCopy AS insolvency_type
     , i.businessNature AS business_nature
     , p.name AS pract_comp_name
     , 'I'     AS i_type 
  FROM insolvencies i
  LEFT JOIN practitioners p ON insolvencies.practitioner = practitioners.id
  CROSS JOIN lookupcopy t 
  WHERE i.checked   =  1    
    AND t.id     =  i.insolvencyType 
    AND i.insolvencyDate    >=  {ts '2010-01-22 00:00:00'} 
    AND i.insolvencyDate    <=  {ts '2011-10-20 00:00:00'} 
    AND (LOWER(p.name)   LIKE   '%Hodgsons%') 
GROUP BY id
```

The `,` between tables is the same as `CROSS JOIN`.

But anyway you should read about `cross join`, `inner join` and `outer join` and use the most appropriate in your case.

Comment: From the [MySQL reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)  `In MySQL, CROSS JOIN is a syntactic equivalent to INNER JOIN (they can replace each other)` So what you've written after the SQL reads kind of funny

Comment: Yeah, but it's good to know the difference and use it according to the standard. Not all RDBMS are MYSQL :)

Answer (score 4):

There are a number of issues here.  First, I took out the commas and properly joined lookupcopy.  I'm not 100% certain of your end goal, but start with the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT i.id AS id,  
                i.company AS company,  
                i.insolvencyDate AS insolvency_date,  
                i.city AS   city,  
                i.createdOn AS createdOn,  
                1 AS rank_id,  
                t.entryCopy AS insolvency_type,  
                i.businessNature AS business_nature,  
                p.name AS pract_comp_name,  
                'I' AS i_type  
    FROM insolvencies i
        INNER JOIN lookupcopy t  on (t.id = i.insolvencyType)
        LEFT JOIN practitioners p ON i.practitioner = p.id
    WHERE i.checked = 1   
        AND i.insolvencyDate >= {ts '2010-01-22 00:00:00'}  
        AND i.insolvencyDate <= {ts '2011-10-20 00:00:00'}  
        AND (LOWER(p.name)   LIKE '%Hodgsons%')  
    GROUP BY id
```

If you continue to have issues, please post your actual error.

Also, one other thing: referencing p.Name in the where clause is going to cause an inner join between practitioners and insolvencies.  Is that intended?

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the comma after `insolvencies i,` to make the `LEFT JOIN` apply to that table, otherwise the `LEFT JOIN` is seen as a stand-alone table to cross-apply, which isn't valid:

```
 FROM insolvencies i
          --        ^ remove comma
     LEFT JOIN...
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your WHERE clause references the LEFT JOIN'ed table

```
WHERE    i.checked   =  1    
        AND t.id     =  i.insolvencyType 
        AND i.insolvencyDate    >=  {ts '2010-01-22 00:00:00'} 
        AND i.insolvencyDate    <=  {ts '2011-10-20 00:00:00'} 
        AND (LOWER(p.name)   LIKE   '%Hodgsons%')
```

If the LEFT JOIN does not find a match, p.Name would be NULL.   By checking p.Name in the WHERE clause, you are making the LEFT JOIN act as a FULL JOIN.   If you need to check for the name, it should be part of the ON expression in the LEFT JOIN